# Flask login sqlite3 database Authentication

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I am creating a login web app that authenticates password, and displays some selected columns from the logged in user, but instead of displaying the selected column for only the logged in user, it displays the selected column for all the users in my database.
below are the codes.

## route for user login

```
def validate4(username,password):
con = sqlite3.connect('static/Users.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Nbc")
    users = cur.fetchall()
    for user in users:
        dbUser = user[0]
        dbPass = user[1]
        if dbPass == password:
            completion=(dbUser, username)
            
            return users   





@app.route('/nbc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def nbc():

if request.method == 'POST':
username = request.form['username']
password = request.form['password']
users= validate4(username,password)

return render_template('nbc.html', users=users)

else:          
     flash ( 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.')
     return render_template('nbc.html')
```

the html template

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/event.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/nbc" method="POST">
        <div class="login">
            <div class="login-screen">
                <div class="app-title">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <input type="text" class="login-field" placeholder="username" name="username" value="{{ request.form.username }}">
                        <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <input type="password" class="login-field" placeholder="password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}">
                        <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block">
                    <br>
                    <div id="navbar" class="app-titl">
                        <a class="nav navbar-nav"></a>
                        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"></a>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    {% if users%}
    <div class="table">
        <table>
            {%for user in users%}
            <ul style="list-style-type:disc">

                <li>{{user[2]}}</li>
                <li>{{user[3]}}</li>
                <li>{{user[4]}}</li>
            </ul>
            {%endfor%}
        </table>
    </div>
    {%endif%}
</body>

</html>
```

help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        return user
```

Instead of:

```
        return users
```

And change:

```
<table>
        {%for user in users%}
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc">

            <li>{{user[2]}}</li>
            <li>{{user[3]}}</li>
            <li>{{user[4]}}</li>
        </ul>
        {%endfor%}
    </table>
```

to:

```
<table>
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc">

            <li>{{user[2]}}</li>
            <li>{{user[3]}}</li>
            <li>{{user[4]}}</li>
        </ul>
    </table>
```

Btw, this query is really inefficient and unsafe. You never check if the username in the database matches the username in the form, you just loop over the passwords until you find a correct one. But what if two persons have the same password? Also; instead of looking up all the users, just query the database looking for the current username. And finally, hash the passwords in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it but it didn't display any result. also i have the same username for all my users, and different passwords. Please how can i make it work?